# Javafx and FXML - Possibility to inject array of ImageView objects

Tags: arrays, javafx, fxml, code-injection

is there a possibility to inject Arrays of `ImageView` Objects?
Or some similar way to reduce the amount of code lines?

So this is what i mean:

```
@FXML
private ImageView led;

@FXML
private ImageView led1;
```

...

```
@FXML
private ImageView led64;
```

Is there something like

```
@FXML
private ImageViewArray led[64];
```

I just want to reduce the amount of lines i have to write 'coz i need MANY of these ImageView Objects and i have to initialize them all. (Maybe there is a better way of doing this, so please come up with everything which could be useful)

Here is the full code:

```
public class guiController implements Initializable {
private static final Image ledOff = new Image("/images/led_white.gif");
private static final Image ledOn = new Image("/images/led_blue.gif");



@FXML
private ImageView led;

@FXML
private ImageView led1;

@FXML
private ImageView led2;
@FXML
private ImageView led3;

@FXML
private ImageView led4;

@FXML
private ImageView led5;

@FXML
private ImageView led6;

@FXML
private ImageView led7;




@FXML
private void handleLedAction(MouseEvent ev){
    ImageView led = (ImageView) ev.getSource();
    if(led.getImage().equals(ledOff)){
        led.setImage(ledOn);
    }   else{
        led.setImage(ledOff);
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    led.setImage(ledOff);
    led1.setImage(ledOff);
    led2.setImage(ledOff);
    led3.setImage(ledOff);
    led4.setImage(ledOff);
    led5.setImage(ledOff);
    led6.setImage(ledOff);
    led7.setImage(ledOff);
   }    

}
```

Comment: Just set up that part of the UI entirely in Java code in the controller's `initialize()` method (instead of in FXML).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

It's just the first time i have to work with that. So i really would appreciate if you could explain how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that many controls, it's probably better to create those in Java instead of in FXML. You can create the container that's going to hold them in the FXML file and then just add the `ImageView`s to them in the controller's `initialize` method.

For example, in the FXML you could do

```
<GridPane fx:id="ledPanel" />
```

and then in the controller

```
private static final Image ledOff = new Image("/images/led_white.gif");
private static final Image ledOn = new Image("/images/led_blue.gif");

@FXML
private GridPane ledPanel ;

private ImageView[] leds ;

public void initialize() {
    final int numLeds = 64 ;
    final int numLedsPerRow = 8 ;

    leds = new ImageView[numLeds];
    for (int i=0; i<numLeds; i++) {
        ImageView led = new ImageView(ledOff);
        leds[i] = led ;
        ledPanel.add(leds[i], i % numLedsPerRow, i / numLedsPerRow);
        led.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            if (led.getImage()==ledOff) {
                led.setImage(ledOn);
            } else {
                led.setImage(ledOff);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(As an aside, since it looks like these are items you are switching on and off with mouse clicks, you might prefer to use `RadioButton`s or `CheckBox`s instead of `ImageView`s, and just use CSS to configure the way they look with your images. That way you get all the event handling and the selected state already coded.)

Comment: Well, sadly i get an error saying: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final... but actually it is no local variable and even if i move it down and make it final i still get the error.

Comment: I tried to edit on my phone. I think that should work now, will check it when I'm back at a computer.